# translating http to RestTemplate

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I have this elasticsearch query that works just fine when I plug it in to a browser:

```
http://my.server:9200/customer/customer/_search?q=age:[0+TO+1]&pretty
```

I'd really like to use it with Spring's RestTemplate:

```
String a = "http://my.server:9200/customer/customer/_search?q=age:[\"0\"+TO+\"1\"]";
String s = restTemplate.getForObject(a, String.class);
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(s);
```

and then access the keys/values via the JSONObject api.

Problem is, I'm getting the error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

from:

```
String s = restTemplate.getForObject(a, String.class);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is ES throwing the 400 ?

you might want to try that :

```
String url = "http://my.server:9200/customer/customer/_search?q={q}
Map params = new LinkedHashMap();
params.put("q", "age:[0 TO 1]");
restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, params)
```

Comment: i tried this.  no errors but it returns too many records.  it should return only 2 records but returns more.

Comment: can you confirm that when you are executing this search directly to ES ( with Sense by example) you get the correct number of results ? 

    ```POST /customer/customer/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "age : [0 TO 1]"
        }
      }
    }```

Comment: when i plug that into Sense i get the 2 expected results.

Comment: Ok, I'm being silly actually, my resttemplate usage is rusty, please check the update in my post